# outgoing url stripping characters

Tags: php, redirect

We use a outgoing url page to direct users to external websites, a la Deviant art style.

The issue I have is twitter feeds, our redirect strips the #!/twitterusername from the url.

Our php is:

```
<?
$goto = $_GET['url'];
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
```

The link html is:

```
<div>
<a class="mini green button" href="<?=$goto;?>">Continue to <span style="text-transform:lowercase !important;"><?=$goto;?></span></a>
 </div>
```

The outgoing URL should be :

```
http://twitter.com/#!/twitterusername
```

However the goto link becomes:

```
http://twitter.com/
```

Any idea why, I am having a blonde moment

Comment: when you `echo` or log `$goto` and `$referrer`, what are their values?

Comment: goto value is http://twitter.com/ and referrer is http://www.oursite.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you do not have the # character encoded properly in the incoming URL. Everything after the # is a local anchor which is not sent to the server. So if you had http://your.site.com/controller?url=http://twitter.com/#!/twitterusername,  everything after the # would be interpreted as a local anchor and not sent to your server. You need to URL encode the parameter.

Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

you need use [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode). That's it.

then do something like

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

echo 'go.php?url=' . urlencode($referrer);
```

`http://twitter.com/#!/twitterusername` will be encoded to `http%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2F%23%21%2Ftwitterusername` which is what you need

Answer (score 0):

You need to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the goto url when you send it to the intermediate page and [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) it before echoing it.

In the page which contains the original link, you need to use

```
<a href="<?=urlencode("http://twitter.com/#!/twitterusername")?>">Twitter</a>
```

Then in the intermediate php, use

```
$goto = urldecode($_GET['url']);
```

Comment: This code doesnt seem to work: <a href="<?=urlencode('outgoing.php?url=http://twitter.com/#!/twitterusername')?>">Twitter</a>
Have I messed it up ?

Comment: yeah you have. Use `<a href="outgoing.php?<?=urlencode('url=twitter.com/#!/twitterusername')?>">Twitter</a>`